# Fullcalendar events, with MVC asp

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, events, fullcalendar

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#calendar').fullCalendar(
    {
        header:
        {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,

        events: function (start, end, callback) {
            var event = [];
            event.push({
                title: 'Garten',
                start: '2013-06-10T00:00:00',
                allday: true
            });

            callback(event);
        }
    });

});
```

Guys thats an event example but what i want is to extract the events from the DataBase, im working with MVC 2 ASP.net and the database is on ADO.Net can anyone help me making an example of how can i extract the data

Answer (score 0):

Ideally a ASP.NET web service should return the data for calendar in JSON format. Kindly refer the following URL: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

Comment: yes but i dont know how to extract the date, this is my algorithmn 
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult List(long start, long end)
        {

        var data = db.eventos.Where(i => i.estado == true).GroupBy(i => i.start).ToList();

        return Json(data.Select(i => new{text = (i.First().title != null) ? i.First().title: "Sin texto",
        allDay = true
        }));
        }